# Mysql with c++ not working

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I tried to connect my program with my database (i had import mysql connector, i don't have boost), but when i compile there's lot of errors

This is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

class Database{
public :
 Database(){};
~Database(){};
void query(const sql::SQLString& query, const sql::SQLString &bdd);

};

void Database::query(const sql::SQLString &query, const sql::SQLString &bdd){

try {
    sql::Driver *driver { };
      sql::Connection *con{ };
      sql::Statement *stmt{ };
      sql::ResultSet *res{ };

      /* Create a connection */
      driver = get_driver_instance();
      con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");

      /* Connect to the MySQL database */
      con->setSchema(bdd);

      stmt = con->createStatement();
      res = stmt->executeQuery(query);

      while (res->next()) {
        cout << "\t... MySQL reponses: ";
        /* Access column data by alias or column name */
        cout << res->getString("content") << endl;
        cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
        /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
        cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
      }
      delete res;
      delete stmt;
      delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
      cout << "# ERR: SQLException a " << __FILE__;
      cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") a la ligne "
         << __LINE__ << endl;
      cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
      cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
      cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Errors :

```
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/warning.h:40:0: warning: 
 ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

  #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
   ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /variant.h:38:0,
             from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /connection.h:10,
             from C:\Program Files\MySQL
 \c++\include/mysql_connection.h:30,
             from ..\src\Database.cpp:10:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/exception.h:48:0: warning: 
 ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

  #pragma warning (disable : 4290)


 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/exception.h:52:0: warning: 
 ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

  #pragma warning(push)


 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/exception.h:53:0: warning: 
 ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

  #pragma warning(disable: 4275)


 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/exception.h:58:0: warning: 
 ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]

  #pragma warning(pop)

 ^

 In file included from ..\src\Database.cpp:10:0:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/mysql_connection.h:174:2: error: 
 'boost' does not name a type

  boost::shared_ptr< NativeAPI::NativeConnectionWrapper > proxy;

  ^

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/mysql_connection.h:178:2: error: 
 'boost' does not name a type

   boost::scoped_ptr< ::sql::mysql::MySQL_Statement > service;

   ^

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/mysql_connection.h:180:2: error: 
 'boost' does not name a type

  boost::scoped_ptr< ::sql::mysql::MySQL_ConnectionData > intern; /* 
 pimpl */

  ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /resultset.h:30:0,
             from ..\src\Database.cpp:13:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/config.h:95:19: error: 
 conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'

 typedef __int32   int32_t;
               ^`enter code here`

 c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:31:14: error: 'int32_t' has a previous 
 declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'

 typedef int  int32_t;
          ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /resultset.h:30:0,
             from ..\src\Database.cpp:13:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/config.h:99:26: error: 
 conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'

  typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                      ^


 c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:32:20: error: 'uint32_t' has a previous 
 declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'

  typedef unsigned   uint32_t;
                ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /statement.h:30:0,
             from ..\src\Database.cpp:14:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/config.h:95:19: error: 
 conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'

 typedef __int32   int32_t;
               ^


 c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:31:14: error: 'int32_t' has a previous 
 declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'

  typedef int  int32_t;
          ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn
 /statement.h:30:0,
             from ..\src\Database.cpp:14:

 C:\Program Files\MySQL\c++\include/cppconn/config.h:99:26: error: 
 conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'

  typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                      ^

 c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:32:20: error: 'uint32_t' has a previous 
 declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'

 typedef unsigned   uint32_t;'
```

I think it's not my program, it's the library but maybe i made a mistake
Thank you and have a good day

Comment: Looks like the mysql connector needs boost and cannot find it, so either you install boost or find a way to disable mysql_connector using boost

Answer (score 0):

obviously your mysqlcpp connector needs boost, so download boost from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) and add the path to the boost folder to your projects additional include directories list. As for the re-definitions comment out the redefined ones in stdint.h.

Comment: Thanks but is there other things to connect to my database (Mysql)? Without boost?

Comment: @Adam Brevet I think since MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.0 mysqlcpp connector binary distributions are compiled using boost library and you need boost.you can get the change log for the library [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-cpp-relnotes-en.a4.pdf)

Comment: @AdamBrevet It may not be a good idea to use the older versions of the MySQL Connector/C++ library just to avoid boost though. Or you can just use the MySQL C API(libmysqlclient) directly(MySQL Connector/C++ is a wrapper for the C API).

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try your idea. Have a good day :)